# Webservice in React

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, web-services, react-tsx

When I define the jsonData object (hardcoded) or when reading the file Project output is working fine. How can I convert that JSON as a file or data processing or can I use mongoDB which is the best possible solution. Without a local input file have to expose the webservice using react and backend

hardcoded, tried using express axios, in postman directly called and output was no file uploaded eventhough file is in path.Attached snaps for reference

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgaES.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7pDs.png)